# Change Gnome menu order in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, menu, context-menu

When I right click on the desktop background image I get a pop-up menu. 99 percent of the time I want to open a new terminal, the bottom option in Ubuntu 18 and also my Red Hat system.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 I find that the "Open in Terminal" option appears in the middle of the list and "Settings" is at the bottom causing me to often make the incorrect election.

How do I alter the order such that "Open in Terminal" again appears at the bottom of the list? I have spent considerable time searching for the answer and find comments about using menu editors to add selections but all I am attempting to do is re-order the existing menu.

Answer (score 1):

This option used to be provided by the file manager, nautilus, in previous versions of Ubuntu. As of 19.04, a Gnome Shell extension "Desktop Icons" is used to provide these right-click context menu's. When the extension is not active, only the selections "Change background", "Display Settings" and "Settings" are available.

There is no user-exposed way to change the right-click menu on the desktop. The only way, currently, to change the order of that menu, would be edit source code. It is my understanding that the extension retrieves the file related right-click options from nautilus. The extension provided menu items are provided on top above the default Gnome Shell menu items.